# 8 byte aligned free contiguous page list in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anybody please tell me if there is any Linux kernel API that can give me free contiguous page list that the starting page address is 8 byte aligned?

I need to get contiguous physical memory but not the virtual memory.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can not just use `kmalloc` ?

Comment: Pages are typically 4096 bytes; as such, all page addresses are necessarily 8-byte aligned.

Comment: i actually need memory in the form of pages specifically. 
@duskwuff: this you are saying on a 32 bit arch or 64 bit. I guess on a 32 bit arch they should be 4 byte aligned, not sure though.

Comment: On most architectures, irrespective of pointer size, pages are 4096 bytes. As a result, they're always 4096-byte aligned, which means they're also 4-byte aligned, 8-byte aligned, 16-byte aligned, 32-byte aligned…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul R says, use `kmalloc`.
If you allocate less than a page, then you allocation will be aligned on its size, rounded up to a power of 2 (i.e. allocating 40 bytes will give you an address aligned on 64 bytes
). If you allocate a page or more, the address is aligned on a page, which is 4096 bytes.
The memory you get is virtual, but is mapped 1-1 to physical memory, so you get contiguous physical pages.
Note that before Linux 2.6.22, it's limited to 128KB (depending on architecture and config). Starting with 2.6.22, the limit is 4MB (again, depending on architecture and config).

Comment: Wrt above:
"Note that it's limited to 128KB (but this limit depends on version and config)."

I wrote a blog post on the kmalloc/vmalloc memory limits:
http://kaiwantech.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/kmalloc-and-vmalloc-linux-kernel-memory-allocation-api-limits/ 

Bottom-line:
The upper limit (number of bytes that can be allocated in a single kmalloc request), is a function of:
the page size and the number of buddy system freelists (MAX_ORDER).

On x86 and ARM 4Kb page size,MAX_ORDER=11, kmalloc: 4 MB
vmalloc limit: in theory, amount of phy RAM (before that 'bad' things will happen- OOM killer!).

Comment: @kaiwan, 128KB is taken from Linux 2.6.18. Starting from 2.6.22, kmalloc was changed and works as you describe.

Comment: Can you please tell me if the page->virtual is also 8 bytes aligned, in case  i have page which is struct * page (returned from get_free_pages()) is 8 byte aligned ?

Comment: A page's virtual and physical address are always aligned on a page size (typically 4K).